# Can't find Control in LinqDataSource Where Control Parameter

Tags: c#, linq, gridview

I'm trying to set up a dropdownlist to filter a gridview. Here's how I'm initializing the ddl:

```
public partial class MyClass : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  DropDownList brList;

  protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    brList = new DropDownList();
    brList.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;
    brList.ID = "ddlBR";
  }

...
```

Later during the gridview's prerender event I build a new gridview row, add the data to the dropdown list and insert it into the first row of the gridview:

```
  //filter for BR
  TableHeaderCell brCell = new TableHeaderCell();
  brList.AutoPostBack = true;
  brList.Items.Add(new ListItem(" ", "%"));
  brList.DataSource = ldsBrCodes;
  brList.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
  brList.DataTextField = "BR";
  brList.DataValueField = "BR";
  brList.DataBind();
  brCell.Controls.Add(brList);
  theNewRow.Cells.Add(brCell);
```

And here is the LinqDataSource that populates the gridview:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="ldsMyLDS" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="DataClassesDataContext" EntityTypeName="" 
    TableName="vwMyReport"  AutoGenerateWhereClause="true">
    <WhereParameters>
      <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="W" Name="MPC" Type="String" />
      <asp:ControlParameter Name="BR" ControlID="ddlBR" Type="String" />
    </WhereParameters>
  </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

I get an error: Could not find control 'ddlBR' in ControlParameter 'BR'.

I'm guessing this is a page life cycle problem and when I'm trying to add this parameter. I've also tried adding the parameter in the code behind as such:

```
ldsMyLDS.WhereParameters.Add(new ControlParameter("paramBR", System.Data.DbType.String, "ddlBR", "BR"));
```

I've added it to the last line of the gridview PreRender event but it still says it can't be found. When Can I add the parameter so the underlying control can be found?

Comment: You need to add the control to the hierarchy (even if its not populated / complete) in Init for it to be available I think

Comment: Why can't you put `ddlBR` directly in the page markup instead of instantiating it programmatically?  Dynamic controls are very difficult to get right, and it's almost always easier if you don't have to do that.

Comment: I would add it in the markup but I have a whole row of filters that I want in the first row of the gridview. I suppose I could build a row outside of the gridview  but it would be tricky matching column widths. I would much rather be able to put the filters in the first tr of the rendered table